# What exactly does '__weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;' mean

Tags: objective-c, typeof, weak

This is used in the weakify pattern of Objective-C

My guess is that it means: assign a weak reference to self with the name 'weakSelf' and the typeof self (e.g. MyViewController)

If it's correct and looks obvious to you: I want to be absolutely sure to get this right. Thanks.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Nice but one has to include `libextobjc/EXTScope`, it is not a part of LLDB. See: [weakify](http://aceontech.com/objc/ios/2014/01/10/weakify-a-more-elegant-solution-to-weakself.html)

Comment: Weakify and Strongify just wrap all that typeof nonsense and suppress some compiler warnings about shadowing self.  It's all the same, but with a few more tricks to make it readable.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: removed dead link

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> My guess is that it means: assign a weak reference to self with the name `weakSelf` and the `typeof` self (e.g. `MyViewController`)

Yes, that is almost exactly what it means. The type of `self` would be `MyViewController*` (with an asterisk) not `MyViewController`.

The idea behind using this syntax instead of simply writing

```
MyViewController __weak *weakSelf = self;
```

is making it easier to refactor the code. The use of `typeof` also makes it possible to define a code snippet that can be pasted anywhere in your code.

Comment: It's supposed to be written `MyViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;`

Answer (score 12):

Using `@weakify` and `@strongify` from [libExtObjC](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTScope.h) helps to simplify the "weak-strong dance" one has to do sometimes around blocks.

*Example!*

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
__weak __typeof(delegate) weakDelegate = delegate;
__weak __typeof(field) weakField = field;
__weak __typeof(viewController) weakViewController = viewController;
[viewController respondToSelector:@selector(buttonPressed:) usingBlock:^(id receiver){
    __strong __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    __strong __typeof(weakDelegate) strongDelegate = weakDelegate;
    __strong __typeof(weakField) strongField = weakField;
    __strong __typeof(weakViewController) strongViewController = weakViewController;
```

versus...

```
@weakify(self, delegate, field, viewController);
[viewController respondToSelector:@selector(buttonPressed:) usingBlock:^(id receiver){
    @strongify(self, delegate, field, viewController);
```

Comment: I think you should mention that this answer requires 'libextobjc'

Comment: @CrimsonChris why do you weakify the delegate? I guess already was.

Comment: If I created the delegate like so... `MyDelegate *delegate = [[MyDelegate alloc] init];` I would have a strong reference to it until the current method ended. It wouldn't matter if the property on `viewController` was weak, I would still be creating a retain cycle if I didn't weakify it.

Answer (score 5):

Your interpretation is correct. However, I find that when it is written that way, it is slightly confusing to read. I prefer it with an additional space after `typeof(self)`:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

Comment: How would you port this to swift- its being used in a library that I am trying to upgrade?

Comment: If it's for a callback block/closure, it's `doSomething() { [weak self] (other, parameters) in doOtherStuff() }`.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your compiler settings, you may get a warning "Expected ';' after expression". You can fix this by changing it to use __typeof like this: `__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;`

Thanks to Leo Natan and this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32145709/1758224.