# "__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;" expected ; at end of declaration

Tags: objective-c

I have two projects open in Xcode 6.4. Both use the follow declaration:

```
- (void)startService
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.messageOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSDictionary *storedMessages = [mySettings get:kStorageName withDefault:@{} storageType:kMySettingsStorageTypeDiskMapped];
        [weakSelf.messages addEntriesFromDictionary:storedMessages];
    }];
}
```

However, in one project there are no errors, and in the other project I get a compiler error:

```
Expected ';' at end of declaration
```

It wants me to put a semi-colon after __weak typeof(self). I have suspicion that I'm just doing something really dumb, but I'm having trouble figuring out what. Also, I know I could replace the `typeof(self)` with `myClass *`.

Comment: Trying to remove this line and rewrite it.

Comment: @Bannings Tried that. Also cleaned and rebuilt. Also restarted Xcode. When I clean, it flashes the error on and off like it can't decide what's going on, ultimately deciding its an error.

Comment: What's in the next line?

Comment: @matt Added the method. This fails in other places with other methods as well in this project. When I replaced them all with `myClass *` it compiles fine.

Comment: This is not relevant to your question, but you do realize, don't you, that you're not doing the weak-strong dance properly and that you can crash when you say `weakSelf.messages`?

Comment: Are you using ARC with this project? If not, try using `__block` instead of `__weak`.

Comment: @LeoNatan `__typeof` worked. Why?

Comment: Was just typing an answer with an explanation when you posted your comment. Good.

Comment: @matt Since weakSelf is weak, it should be nil-ed when it goes out of memory and sending a message to nil should be safe, yes?

Comment: `weakSelf.message` will not crash. `weakSelf->message` will, which is one of the few reasons why properties are preferred over ivars.

Comment: @matt "Fetching" a property is actually calling the getter method of the property. Calling that method on a nil objects results in a nil result, not a crash.

Comment: @LeoNatan Ah, okay. One less thing to worry about. Still, I was taught to assign `weakSelf` to a strong reference first thing and proceed only if this is not `nil`. (It's been a while since I did this; I live in Swift these days...)

Comment: @matt This is for another reason. If you have several code lines accessing the same weak variable, it may be released in the middle, causing undefined behaviour in your code. This way, you hold it strongly for the duration of scope.

Comment: @matt Aside from different semantics of Swift, properties are implemented exactly the same way. Internally, the Swift runtime is calling all the ObjC runtime functions we love. `;)`

Comment: @LeoNatan Yes, but my point is that Swift makes it much easier to get the dance right. It basically twists your arm and forces you to do so. :)

Comment: @matt Which I am not necessarily fond of. But to be honest, ARC did a most things right. If Apple were to go a little step further and provide a hint system to tell the compiler/runtime how to capture scoped objects, it would have been perfect in ObjC long before Swift. Let's admit it, `__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;` is ugly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `__typeof` instead of `typeof`.

This is because both `__typeof` and `typeof` are extensions to C, but `typeof` is only enabled in Clang when the language is a `GNUXX` variant of C, but not for `CXX`.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error. @Leo Natan is right and if you want, you can change the C dialect to GNU like this:

In the Project Navigator go to Project -> Target -> Build Settings

There look for C Language Dialect and change it from c11 or c99 to GNU99 and it will solve the problem. Now you can use typeof()

I hope it helps :)

Comment: This really should be set to `Compiler Default`.